# How NOT to get a new line in the assignment with a call to a shell utility

Tags: perl, newline

#### Situation

I am absolutely new to Perl and have to modify a subroutine in an existing script. The starting point is:

```
sub example {

    my $program = $ENV{'FC'};

    unless ( $variable ) {

        foreach ( 'gfortran', 'g95' ) {
            $compiler = $_;
            my $path  = `which $program`;
            last if $path;
        }
    }

    return $program;
}
```

#### Issue

This works perfectly when `FC=gfortran` and returns `gfortran`. In my case, however, the same environment variable has to be `FC=\opt\gcc\bin\gfortran`

#### Research

I have tried to change the second line

```
my $program = $ENV{'FC'};  # original
```

into

```
my $program = `basename $ENV{'FC'}`;  # with a call to a shell utility
```

which works out as desired to an extent, since the function output contains an annoying extra new line:

```
'gfortran
 '
```

that spoils the functioning of the code father down. The assignment should be a plain `gfortran`.

#### Question

How can I suppress that automatic new line?

Answer (score 2):

You could remove it

```
chomp($program);
```

Better yet, use

```
use File::Basename qw( basename );

sub example {
    if ( my $program = $ENV{FC} ) {
        return basename($program);
    }

    for my $program (qw( gfortran g95 )) {
        return $program if `which $program`;
    }

    return undef;
}
```

Comment: Not inclined to edit the structure of the code for portability in future discussion (option 2). Re option 1, where should I add `chomp($program)` precisely? I see that the output of a `print chomp($program)` is a number which I did not expect

Comment: @XavierStuvw as per `perldoc -f chomp`, it returns the number of (newline) characters removed. It modifies the passed value(s), so just `chomp($value)` and use `$value`. I'd recommend the `File::Basename` approach, though.

Comment: *"Not inclined to edit the structure of the code for portability"* You have the choice between your code being correct or "portably" faulty.